# Customise Colours of Side by Side (Dodged) Bar Chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a customized color palette for each group used within a side-to-side bar chart.

```
#Setup Values & DataFrame
class_list <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
values_1   <- c(0.45,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.55,0.45,0.3)
values_2   <- c(0.4,0.45,0.3,0.45,0.4,0.55,0.4)
df <- data.frame(class=class_list, v1=values_1, v2=values_2)

#Melt Dataframe 
df_plot <- melt(df, id.vars='class')

#Create Colour Palette
colour_palette = c("#CDF57A","#ABCE66","#375623","#FFFF00","#A87000","#732600","#FF0000")
  
#Create Dodged Bar Chart 
p <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=class, y=value, fill=class, family=variable)) + theme_classic()
p <- p + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', colour='black') 
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = colour_palette) + theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

Which produces:

Expected Output From Code

[image]

However, I am trying to create something like this:

Desired Output

[image]

(Ideally, instead of one color, I can have another custom palette)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your desired result you could map both `class` and `variable` on `fill` using e.g. `interaction`.

As an example of how to add a second platte I simply reversed your color palette to duplicate the number of colors:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#Setup Values & DataFrame
class_list <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
values_1   <- c(0.45,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.55,0.45,0.3)
values_2   <- c(0.4,0.45,0.3,0.45,0.4,0.55,0.4)
df <- data.frame(class=class_list, v1=values_1, v2=values_2)

#Melt Dataframe 
df_plot <- melt(df, id.vars='class')

#Create Colour Palette
colour_palette = c("#CDF57A","#ABCE66","#375623","#FFFF00","#A87000","#732600","#FF0000")
colour_palette <- c(colour_palette, rev(colour_palette))
#Create Dodged Bar Chart 
p <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x=class, y=value, fill=interaction(class, variable))) + theme_classic()
p <- p + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', colour='black') 
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values = colour_palette) + theme(legend.position="none")
p
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much 